# IzPack: Require at least one of multiple packs

Tags: plugins, izpack

I've got a software that consists of different plugins that can be selected during installation in IzPack. These plugins provide different features to the software: input, processing, output. The software needs at least one input and output plugin to work.
How do I specify that **at least** one plugin providing a certain feature is selected in the PackPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this was implemented in izpack v5.0.0-rc5 and newer. PacksPanel does not allow you to continue if you have deselected all the options.

[image]

Based on your comment I would solve this by using conditionvalidator:
Basically add condition for each of your packs:

```
<condition type="packselection" id="pack1inputselected">
  <name>Pack 1 input</name>
</condition>
```

Then make OR conditions with groups of your packs (input, processing, output), e.g. like this:

```
<condition type="or" id="inputgroup">
  <condition type="ref" refid="pack1inputselected" />
  <condition type="ref" refid="pack2inputselected" />
</condition>
```

Then add a final AND validation condition (id is crucial as it has to always start by conditionvalidator word! The conditionvalidator class gets to validate all the conditions starting with conditionvalidator.):

```
<condition type="and" id="conditionvalidator.packsselected">
  <condition type="ref" refid="inputgroup" />
  <condition type="ref" refid="processinggroup" />
  <condition type="ref" refid="outputgroup" />
</condition>
```

Add conditionvalidator to PacksPanel in panels element:

```
<panel classname="PacksPanel" id="panel.packs">
  <validator classname="com.izforge.izpack.installer.validator.ConditionValidator" />
</panel>
```

There. Everytime the condition that is validated (when clicking on next) by conditionvalidator will not be true (that is if you will not have the correct packs selected), it will throw a message and will not allow you to continue. You can change the message by adding string to CustomLangPack with .error.message (e.g. in this example conditionvalidator.packsselected.error.message).

Comment: It is a native functionality of this panel since this version, at least one pack has to be always selected (be it one with required="yes" attribute) or one of the non-mandatory packs

Comment: That's nice but I need something like groups of packs which the user has to choose at least one pack from for each group.

Comment: I have updated the answer, which should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: This almost works as expected. Thank you. Why is the button disabled in your screenshot? And how is the message triggered?

Comment: The button is disabled because there is no pack selected in the PacksPanel (it really works only in newer izpack versions, in earlier it did not disable the next button). The message is triggered by the condition conditionvalidator.packsselected being equal to false.